# JS getElementById from created Element

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, getelementbyid

im trying to get a certain part from a html document. As I try to fire getElementById on the created element the debuggers tells me that `getElementById()` is not a function. `getElementsByTagNames()` works, but the number of div's is changing in the original html document when the website gets new content, so i get the wrong result.

Can someone help me please? I want this to work:

```
function parse(str) {
     var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
     el.innerHTML=str;
     el.getElementById( 'results' );
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById - please read - you can only search the document - and where is element with id `results`? In the string you're passing?

Comment: An id must be unique in a document, why do you need to limit the scope of the search?

Answer (score 0):

[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) doesn't have defined `getElementById()` method thus your didn't worked.

As an alternative,  You can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

```js
var str = '<div><span id="results">1</span></div>'
var el = document.createElement('html');
el.innerHTML = str;
console.log(el.querySelector('#results'));
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what i was looking for:)